# How to calculate percentage with generics in Swift?

Tags: swift, generics

I would do following conversion if `width == 200` then

```
20 -> 40
20.0 -> 40.0
```

So it should work for both `Int` and `Double`.

```swift
let width = 333

func unitX<T>(x: T) -> T {
    return width * x / 100
}
```

but get this error:

> Binary operator '*' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Int' and 'T'

What can I do?

Comment: Even if your code did work, `x / 100` is integer division, which truncates and isn't what you want.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you wanting to use generics for this? You only really need to define your function for `Double` values and _maybe_ `Int`/`Int32` - which can be separate overloads.

Comment: @Dai  `separate overloads` good idea :)

Comment: Look at how the Swift header defines operators (like `*`). Is it generic? No. It's a different operator overload for every single numeric type. That should tell you something.

Comment: @matt I haven't been a Swift user for 4 years now, but isn't all in `protocol Numeric` now? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/numeric - it defines all the arithmetic operators (along with `protocol AdditiveArithmetic`)? (hmm, except division and modulo/remainder for some reason)

Comment: @Dai Protocols, yes, but not _generics_.

Comment: If you pursue separate overloads, rather than doing ones for individual, specific, numeric types, you might do ones for relevant protocols, e.g. `func unitX<T: BinaryInteger>(x: T) -> T {  T(width) * x / T(100) }` and another for `BinaryFloatingPoint`, etc. That will reduce the number of separate overloads you have to do.

Comment: @matt I thought protocols can be used to constrain generic type parameter arguments? e.g. `Add<T>( T x, T y ) -> T where T : AdditiveArithmetic { return x + y; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

...If Generic is really the way you want to go with this:

You'll want to start by defining some constraints on T to constrain it to a type that make sense to take a percentage of. From there, you'll simply need to iterate the possibilities and cast, or define your own operator on a protocol you're conforming to.

You can read about custom operators here: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/AdvancedOperators.html

In theory you could do something like this:

```
protocol Percentable {
    var value: Double {get, set}
}

extension Percentable {
    static prefix func % () -> Percentable {
        // DO percentage logic here 
        return value
    }
}
```

And then you could call this like the following:

```
func unitX<T>(x: T) -> T where T: Percentable {
    return x %
}
```

Note: You would have to then make an extension on Int or Double to be Percentable.

## Recap

This would be a **horrible** approach since you would simply be converting from and Int to a Double back to an Int. It would make more sense (like mentioned in the comments) to simply overload Ints to divide by Doubles and visa-versa to keep your precision. Generics **are not** a good use here.